# Email does not send when there is dots in the body

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to send a password recovery email in my php web site. Let's say my domain is `test`. When I'm giving the recovery url I have to use `test.com`. but when I use that email does not send. I tried with `testcom`. (without a dot). then email is sending successfully. Why is that? sample code is as follow.

```
$remail="testing@gmail.com";
$to=reciev@gmail.com;
$subject="Reset Password!";
$headers="From: " . $remail;
$body=" Hello User,
You can reset your password from following link.
http://test.com/do-forget.php?email=$e&key=$key
Regards,
";
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Comment: it is in 12th position.i removed dot in do-forget.php. then email sent successfully. Issue is when there are 2 dots.

Comment: Never mind then. I'd suggest checking the other questions on this site about php's mail function failing.

Comment: i don`t think there is a error in mail function.Is there any limitations when use dots in email body??

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224224/smtp-dot-stuffing-when-and-where-to-do-it) had something to do with it.  Honestly,  haven't had much trouble with mail but I use a php mail library to write my mail. You might want to give that a shot.

Comment: This is a non-working code sample. Please sahre the actual code you're testing with.

Comment: i think u pointing `http://test.com/do-forget.php?email=$e&key=$key`this. but lets update it like this. `http://test.com/do-forget.php` still same error because there are two dots